# Can be used only in the preamble error - and yes, it's in the preamble

Tags: compiling, preamble

I have these lines

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[font=small,skip=2pt]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{{Images}{../Images/}}

\input{commands} % global vars and fucntions

\begin{document}
```

...

when I try to compile this with texmaker using MiKTeX Windows 10, I get the error that lines 3, 4 and 5 (the ones with \usepackage) should be in the preamble. Aren't they?
These are the only errors in the project, my commands.tex is getting recognized just fine.

Comment: The preamble can terminate early, but you should get a message for that as well.  BTW, I crash on your document class.

Comment: it is very hard to debug a fragment of code that references files not shown, please edit the question to provide a test file (or files) that shows the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I was hoping this was a fairly common error. I'll try to reduce the project to a minimum and if the error persists, I'll get back to you.
Just FYI: the .tex is in a folder called Chapters, it's included in the main.tex which is in the root folder, using the package subfiles.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your file to compile, just remove the preamble from sub file and put it in the main.tex only (this preamble will be shared by all sub files of main).

If you want an explanation of why the error message is misleading, I can't help.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was hoping it would be a noob mistake like this.